# CORS issue when client calls server which calls external api

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I am attempting to implement a 0Auth 2.0 flow for the spotify api.

If i call my node server from my client, I get a cors issue but if navigate straight to my server url, it works fine.

Here is the error i get in dev tools when attemptin

```
localhost/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?client_id=eca82f597115423cac9d1125e0fb97c4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8888/callback&scope=user-top-read' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/login') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

The server is running on localhost:8888
client on :3000

Server:

```
    var SpotifyWebApi = require("spotify-web-api-node");
var cors = require("cors");
const express = require("express");

const app = express();
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:8888" }));
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "localhost:8888"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  );
  next();
});

const scopes = ["user-top-read"];

var spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
  clientId: "eca82f597115423cac9d1125e0fb97c4",
  clientSecret: "17a6e5916bb3424eb50f29e4816521a4",
  redirectUri: "http://localhost:8888/callback",
});

app.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
    "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
  ); // If needed
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "X-Requested-With,content-type"
  ); // If needed
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);


  //ISSUE IS HERE
  if (!spotifyApi.getAccessToken()) {
    res.redirect(spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(scopes));
  } else {
    res.send("ass");
  }
});

app.get("/callback", (req, res) => {
  console.log(res);
  const error = req.query.error;
  const code = req.query.code;
  const state = req.query.state;

  if (error) {
    console.error("Callback Error:", error);
    res.send(`Callback Error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }

  spotifyApi
    .authorizationCodeGrant(code)
    .then((data) => {
      const access_token = data.body["access_token"];
      const refresh_token = data.body["refresh_token"];
      const expires_in = data.body["expires_in"];

      spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      spotifyApi.setRefreshToken(refresh_token);

      console.log("access_token:", access_token);
      console.log("refresh_token:", refresh_token);

      console.log(
        `Sucessfully retreived access token. Expires in ${expires_in} s.`
      );

      res.send("Success! You can now close the window.");

      setInterval(async () => {
        const data = await spotifyApi.refreshAccessToken();
        const access_token = data.body["access_token"];

        spotifyApi.setAccessToken(access_token);
      }, (expires_in / 2) * 1000);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error getting Tokens:", error);
      res.send(`Error getting Tokens: ${error}`);
    });
});

app.get("/getTopTracks", (req, res) => {
  spotifyApi.getMyTopTracks().then(function (data) {
    res.send(data.body.items);
  });
});

app.listen(8888, () =>
  console.log(
    "HTTP Server up. Now go to http://localhost:8888/login in your browser."
  )
);
```

client:

```
   function FunctionalComponent() {
  const [topTracks, settopTracks] = useState([]);

  function handleOnClick() {
    axios.get("/login").then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>Click here to login</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FunctionalComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

from MDN : `For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy.`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

so as you understand, this restriction comes from browser blocking requests to cross origin domains, and specifically requests coming from scripts, not from navigation url itself, well, since it did not come from script.